# Multiple file uploads with PHP script and iOS

Tags: php, objective-c, macos

Currently I'm uploading a xml file from mac to a server. It works fine. Below is the code:

***osx code***

```
  NSString *urlString1 = @"http://username:pwd@ip/files/upload.php";


NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request1 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString1]];
[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



NSString *boundary1 = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary1];
[request1 addValue:contentType1 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body1 = [NSMutableData data];
[body1 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body1 appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"data.xml\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body1 appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body1 appendData:[NSData dataWithData:xmlData]];
[body1 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request1 setHTTPBody:body1];
NSLog(@"xml data %@",xmlData);
NSData *returnData1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

and ***PHP script***:

```
 <?php
  $target_path = "./";
  $target_path = $target_path.'data.xml';
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$target_path)) {
    echo "The file has been uploaded";
  } else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
  }
?>
```

Now I have a case where I'm supposed to add multiple files. So how does file naming work? Anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check with the PHP Array function if it works it is good. I am not sure about XCode but lets stick to the Basic HTML for for uploading multiple Files. Try the below code:

Multiple files can be selected and then uploaded using the

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' multiple>
```

The sample php script that does the uploading:

```
<html>
<title>Upload</title>
<?php
    session_start();
    $target=$_POST['directory'];
        if($target[strlen($target)-1]!='/')
                $target=$target.'/';
            $count=0;
            foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) 
            {
                $temp=$target;
                $tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count];
                $count=$count + 1;
                $temp=$temp.basename($filename);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp,$temp);
                $temp='';
                $tmp='';
            }
    header("location:../../views/upload.php");
?>
</html>
```

The selected files are received as an array with

$_FILES['file']['name'][0] storing the name of first file. $_FILES['file']['name'][1] storing the name of second file. and so on.